# Shell script split a string by space

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, subshell

The bash shell script can split a given string by space into a 1D array.

```
str="a b c d e"
arr=($str)

# arr[0] is a, arr[1] is b, etc. arr is now an array, but what is the magic behind?
```

But, what exactly happened when we can `arr=($str)`? My understanding is the parenthesis here creates a subshell, but what happen after that?

Comment: How do you want backslashes to be handled? If you have `a\ b c d e`, should the first element be `a b` or ```a\```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an assignment, the parentheses simply indicate that an array is being created; this is independent of the use of parentheses as a compound command.

This isn't the recommended way to split a string, though. Suppose you have the string

```
str="a * b"
arr=($str)
```

When `$str` is expanded, the value undergoes both word-splitting (which is what allows the array to have multiple elements) and pathname expansion. Your array will now have `a` as its first element, `b` as its last element, but one or more elements in between, depending on how many files in the current working directly `*` matches. A better solution is to use the `read` command.

```
read -ra arr <<< "$str"
```

Now the `read` command itself splits the value of `$str` without also applying pathname expansion to the result.

Comment: It's not specific to `read`; it's a special redirection operator. `read` takes its input from standard input. Whereas `read < file.txt` would take its standard input from the file named `file.txt`, `read <<< text` reads directly from the given string. It's a short-cut for a one-line here document.

Comment: Might want `read -r -a`, unless the OP explicitly wants backslashes to impact grouping.

Comment: My muscle memory only permits `read -r` or `read -a`, not both :)

Comment: `read -ar` actually assigns to an array named `r`. My suggestion of `read -r -a` was deliberate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've confused

```
arr=($str) # An array is created with word-splitted str
```

with

```
(some command) # executing some command in a subshell
```

---

Note that

`arr=($str)` is different from `arr=("$str")`in that in the latter, the double quotes prevents word splitting ie the array will contain only one value -> `a b c d e`.

You can check the difference between the two by the below

```
echo "${#arr[@]}"
```